# How to store Base64 image sent from client in BlobStore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, blob, blobstore

I am extremely new to BlobStore, I am receiving a Base64 image from the client
I am converting it like this:

```
byte [] picByte = Base64.decodeBase64(pic);
Blob blob = new Blob(picByte);
```

I am using jersey 2 and my goal is to save this picture and later get the serving link `blobstoreService.serve`

How can I save this image with jersey 2?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    byte[] picByte = Base64.decodeBase64(pic);
    GcsFileOptions instance = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("image/jpeg").build();
    GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename("xxx-app.appspot.com", "someName.jpg");
    GcsOutputChannel outputChannel;
    GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
    outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, instance);
    ByteBuffer a = ByteBuffer.wrap(picByte);
    outputChannel.write(a);
    outputChannel.close();
```